# ssh-keygen Invalid ECDSA key length even with valid key length

Tags: windows, openssh

What am I doing wrong? This works perfectly on OS X/Linux.

```
C:\Users\Prashanth> ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521
Invalid ECDSA key length - valid lengths are 256, 384 or 521 bits
```

I'm using `openssh 0.0.3.0` from chocolatey, which seems to correspond to `OpenSSH_7.1p1 Microsoft_Win32_port_with_VS, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015`

Comment: do the other sizes work? It looks like disabled in OpenSSL

Comment: I think you're right, didn't work with other sizes either. I'm using the latest OpenSSH on Windows which seems to be a new project by Microsoft with homemade crypto. I uninstalled that, used an older version of OpenSSH for Windows and it works.